# How do you prevent Drupal 8 from redirecting to the page when a new page has been created?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

When you create a new page in Drupal 8 it redirects the user to that page on the site, I would like it to redirect back to the content section of the Admin interface.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom module and use

[hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x)

You would start by checking what form it is and then add a custom submit callback like so

```
function your_module_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // test you are altering the correct form so wrap the below in an IF
  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = '_your_module_custom_redirect';
}

function _your_module_custom_redirect($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setRedirect('your route name');
}
```

or possibly use [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/8.2.x) as I think hook_form_alter will run regardless of validation, but I am not 100% on that